# Spany 2 with MigLayout with one row

Tags: java, position, miglayout

Abstract:
I want to let one component span two rows, although there is only one row available. The following screenshots will illustrate my problem. You will find a SSCCE at the end to test things out if you want to.

I have come along with a workaround, but I want to know if there is any better solution for this.

---

### Case 1

There are two rows created, because enough elements have been added:
[image: Enough rows]

Relevant code:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 7, debug, fill", "grow, fill", "grow, fill"));
int n = 8;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(new Color(rand.nextInt()));
    if(i == 2) {
        panel.add(p, "spany 2");
    }
    else {
        panel.add(p, "");
    }
}
```

So when the 8th panel is added, MigLayout automatically wraps it and there are two rows. Now the 3rd panel can span two rows.

### Case 2

There is only one row:
[image: Not enough rows]

Relevant code change:

```
int n = 7;
```

So the row is filled with 7 panels, but MigLayout doesn't wrap to a new row and then the 3rd panel cannot span two rows.

### Case 3

This is my workaround:
[image: Workaround]

Relevant code change:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 7, debug, fill", "grow, fill", "[grow, fill][grow, fill]"));
```

So I kinda tell MigLayout that there are two rows and so the 3rd element can span two rows. The problem is that I don't know how many rows there will be (or let's say it is inconvenient to compute it)

**Is there any other possibility to achive this? My goal is to dynamically enlarge single panels to their double heigth.**

---

SSCCE:

```
public class MigPositionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MigPositionTest(); //Yes it is not started within EventDispatcher
    }

    private Random rand = new Random(123);

    public MigPositionTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("MigLayout Span Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 7, debug, fill", "grow, fill", "grow, fill"));

        int n = 8;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.setBackground(new Color(rand.nextInt()));

            if(i == 2) {
                panel.add(p, "spany 2");
            }
            else {
                panel.add(p, "");
            }

        }

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `span` does not create a new column or row for us. There has to be
other components in the other column or row. `FormLayout` works the 
same.

I came with two possible solutions.

**Solution 1**

We can use the `w` constraint to set the preferred size of the panels.
The taller panels gets double size:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigPanels extends JFrame {

    public MigPanels() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Spanning");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 5"));

        pnl.add(createPanel(), "w 50, h 150, top");
        pnl.add(createPanel(), "w 50, h 150, top");
        pnl.add(createPanel(), "w 50, h 300");
        pnl.add(createPanel(), "w 50, h 150, top");
        pnl.add(createPanel(), "w 50, h 150, top");

        add(pnl);

        pack();
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        return pnl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigPanels ex = new MigPanels();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Spanning]

**Solution 2**

We put a dummy label to the second row:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigPanels2 extends JFrame {

    public MigPanels2() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Spanning");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 5"));

        pnl.add(createPanel());
        pnl.add(createPanel());
        pnl.add(createPanel(), "growy, spany 2");
        pnl.add(createPanel());
        pnl.add(createPanel());

        // dummy label
        pnl.add(new JLabel(""), "cell 0 1, w 50, h 150");  

        add(pnl);

        pack();
    }

    private JPanel createPanel() {

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(50, 150);
            }              
        };

        pnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        return pnl;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigPanels2 ex = new MigPanels2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```